# React Native can't find .android.tsx and .ios.tsx files

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I am trying to publish my app with Expo. It fails because

```sh
Unable to resolve module components/MainButton could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\node_modules
```

MainButton is a .android.tsx and .ios.tsx file.

Any info on why it can't find my component?

PS: I am using absolute paths

Here is part of what I am trying to do

[Components naming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itNTZ.png)

[Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drcqm.png)

[Babel config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd1X6.png)

Comment: Any additional info on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to have different files for android and ios when importing Button.tsx. It work on JavaScript but not with Typescript. @NicholasMberev